# Recursive way of parsing xml file

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm looking for a way to recursively parse an xml file, no matter what kind of structure it has, and get the attributes/values inside that element or tag. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean: "No matter what kind of structure it has" and "get the attributes/values inside THAT element or tag" . The second quote implies to me that you know what the structure is. Anyways, you cannot parse a xml document without knowing what you want to search for.

Comment: http://lokesh2011.blogspot.com/2011/05/java-recursive-program-to-read-xml-file.html?showComment=1323317718965#c172244695528789874

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds like a description of XSLT. Have you looked at using XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SAX parser:

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser

Comment: tried this but i'm still looking for other options dealing with unknown hierarchies of nodes/elements

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it to be recursively?
If its not a requirement than you can look at this tutorial its very good
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Comment: just thought if i can do it recursively, i tried this one too, still lost, or maybe i'm loosing something, my bad. :((